# Why isn't urls.py generated with django-admin startapp mysite?

Tags: python, django

But instead has to be created by the user.

```
 project
 |
 +-- settings.py
 +-- mysite
     |
     +-- views.py
     +-- apps.py
     +-- models.py
     +-- * user created urls.py file *
```

Comment: same goes for forms.py and it would also be nice to have a template folder initialized when you start an app. I don't know good point but that is something you should ask at https://www.djangoproject.com

Comment: There is a feature request marked as `wontfix`: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25943

Comment: Note that [`startproject`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#startproject) and [`startapp`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#startapp) both have a `--template` option that allow you to customize the project/app that is created.

Answer (score 10):

An app doesn't need to have urls, views, or anything at all. It can also just be a collection of templates or be a middleware. Therefore these files have to be created by the user when needed.

Comment: I never understood this.  While an app doesn't *need* to have URLs, it doesn't *need* to have models (or an admin section), yet those are created.  It's easier to delete than create.  I have a "standard" urls.py file that I copy into new apps that has list, create, update, and delete views in it (and commented out) so I can get rocking easier.